# draw common axis in groupplots over two groups

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots, axis

I have a `groupplot` with size `2 by 1` and want to draw a common axis over both groups. This is what I have

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      group name=my plots,
      group size=2 by 1,
      ylabels at=edge left,
      xlabels at=edge bottom,
      horizontal sep=0pt
    },
    yticklabels={,,},
    xticklabels={,,},
    ]

    \nextgroupplot[
    tickpos=left,
    xlabel=$x_2$,
    ylabel=$x_3$,
    xmin=-0.5, xmax=10.5,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=10.5,
    ]
    \addplot [red, only marks, samples=50, mark size=0.75, domain=0:10] {5+5*rand)};
    \nextgroupplot[
    xtick pos = left,
    ytick pos = right,
    xlabel=$x_2$,
    ylabel=$x_3$,
    xmin=-0.5, xmax=10.5,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=10.5,
    ]
    \addplot [red, only marks, samples=50, mark size=0.75, domain=0:10] {5+5*rand)};
  \end{groupplot}

  \begin{axis}[
    hide y axis,
    axis x line=top,
    xlabel=$x_1$,
    tick align=inside,    
    xticklabels={,,},
    xmin=0, xmax=1,
    scale=2,
    ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately the additional axis is plotted above the groupplots figure. How can I align this axis?

In addition, how can I add arrows to the groupplots axes?
`axis line style=->` is not working.

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were after? I set the `anchor` and position (with `at`) of the last `axis`, so its top left corner is placed at the top left corner of the `groupplot`. For the arrow tips on the axes, you might need to add `separate axis lines`, so the four sides of the axis are drawn as separate paths.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border = 2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      group name=my plots,
      group size=2 by 1,
      ylabels at=edge left,
      xlabels at=edge bottom,
      horizontal sep=0pt,
    },
    yticklabels={},
    xticklabels={},
    xlabel=$x_2$,
    separate axis lines, % <-- added
    axis x line=bottom,  % <-- added
    axis line style={-stealth, line cap=rect},
    xmin=-0.5, xmax=10.5,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=10.5,
    ]

    \nextgroupplot[
      tickpos=left,
      ylabel=$x_3$,
    ]
    \addplot [red, only marks, samples=50, mark size=0.75, domain=0:10] {5+5*rand)};

    \nextgroupplot[
    xtick pos = left,
    ytick pos = right,
    ylabel=$x_3$,
    ]
    \addplot [red, only marks, samples=50, mark size=0.75, domain=0:10] {5+5*rand)};
  \end{groupplot}


  \begin{axis}[
    anchor=north west, % <-- added
    at=(my plots c1r1.north west),  % <-- added
    hide y axis,
    axis x line=top,
    xlabel=$x_1$,
    tick align=inside,    
    xticklabels={},
    xmin=0, xmax=1,
    scale=2,
    ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```